# How do you clear a form in C# while keeping user input data?

Tags: c#, save

I am writing a program for customizing drinks. The program lets the user select a size, flavor, topping, and quantity. The user then presses the button "Add drink to order" and a message pops up "Do you want to customize another drink to add to your order? Yes, No" My question is how do you save the first customized drink to print in the receipt along with the second drink? When clearing the form the data is lost correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your program has to save the data.  This can be into a database, or into a collection.  I don't think you are using a database yet, so a collection is the best way.

Create a class that has a property for each type of value. Then make a list of those, populated with values.

Answer (score 1):

First build an object that represents the order

```
public class DrinkOrder
{
  public Object Size { get; set; }
  public Object Flavor { get; set; }
  public Object Topping { get; set; }
  public Object Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

*Note: I use the vague `Object` type because I don't know how you're representing those field values*

Then add a list to your form that retains the past/future "orders"

```
List<DrinkOrder> Orders = new List<DrinkOrder>();
```

Then, when they click add, populate the object and add it to the list of orders.

```
private void btnPlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  /* ... */

  this.Orders.Add(new DrinkOrder
  {
    Size = this.SizeControl.Value,
    Flavor = this.FlavorControl.Value,
    Toppings = this.ToppingControl.value
    Quantity = this.QuantityControl.Value
  });

  /* ... */
}
```

Then, you can clear the forms (if desired) and be ready to do it all over again.

Once they're done placing orders, you now have a list (`Orders`) you can reference as a "shopping cart".

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! By the way, where should the list be placed in the form?

Comment: @jmendegan: Keep it as a private variable within the form's class, just below (presumably) `class Form1 {` (unless it needs to be accessed by other forms, then you're going to have to make a decision on correct scope/encapsulation)

Comment: Ok thanks. Should these variables in the class be abstract? Example: public abstract string Size {get; set;}     It's giving many errors about abstract or extern

Comment: abstract is a class declaration, meaning it needs to be inherited. extern is for DLLs. You'll probably want `private`, `protected` or `public`

Comment: I've been looking up info about the errors and about using classes as data holders. But I'm becoming more confused the more I read. Can you explain the concept of using the class you described above?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could put the data somewhere? Like an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Binding for this, it's easy and saves multiple data. You can read more about it [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html)